# How to persist nested documents in mongodb Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to save a document in MongoDb with a json format like this

```
{
    "userId": "5b89411a161aef03a2ac6847",
    "stocks": [
        {
            "symbol": "aapl",
            "company": "Apple Inc",
            "group": [
                {
                    "quantity": 110,
                    "date": "2018-09-02 14:33:51",
                    "price": "215.00",
                    "type": "SEC"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a mongoRepository setup like this

```
public interface UserBuyingRepository extends MongoRepository<BoughtStocks, String>{
    BoughtStocks findByUserId(String userId);
}
```

Then I have a controller which gets the userId and symbol and the quantity and now if the user has already bought a stock I would like to add it as the next item in the `group` and if he has not bought a stock I would like add it as the next item in the `stocks`. My Controller looks like this and I am stuck here.

```
@GetMapping("/buy/{symbol}/{quantity}")
    public String userBuyingStock(@PathVariable("userID") String userId,
                                  @PathVariable(value = "symbol") String symbol, @PathVariable(value = "quantity") int quantity) {   

        BoughtStocks boughtStocks = userBuyingRepo.findByUserId(userId);

        String date = "2018-9-23"
        if(boughtStocks == null){
            Group group = new Group();
            group.setDate(date);
            group.setPrice(213);
            group.setQuantity(quantity);
            group.setType("SEC");

            List<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
            groupList.add(group);

            Stock stock = new Stock();
            stock.setSymbol(symbol);
            stock.setCompany("Apple Inc");
            stock.setGroup(groupList);

            List<Stock> stockList = new ArrayList<>();
            stockList.add(stock);

            boughtStocks = new BoughtStocks();
            boughtStocks.setUserId(applicationUser.getId());
            boughtStocks.setStocks(stockList);
        }else{
            Group group = new Group();
            group.setDate(date);
            group.setPrice(213);
            group.setQuantity(quantity);
            group.setType("SEC");

            List<Group> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
            groupList.add(group);
            Stock stock = new Stock();
            stock.setSymbol(symbol);
            stock.setCompany("Apple Inc");
            stock.setGroup(groupList);
            boughtStocks.getStocks().add(stock);
        }
        userBuyingRepo.save(boughtStocks);
        return company.getCompanyName();
    }
```

My models are like this

BoughtStocks.java

```
public class BoughtStocks {
    @Id
    private String userId;
    private List<Stock> stocks = null;


    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public List<Stock> getStocks() {
        return stocks;
    }

    public void setStocks(List<Stock> stocks) {
        this.stocks = stocks;
    }

}
```

Stock.java

```
public class Stock {
    @Id
    private String symbol;
    private String company;
    private List<Group> group = null;


    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public List<Group> getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(List<Group> group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

}
```

Groups.java

```
public class Group {

    private Integer quantity;
    private String date;
    private String price;
    private String type;


    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

I am missing out on a basic concept here. I have tried using this

```
@Query(value = "{'userId':'?0','stocks.symbol':'?1'}",fields = "{'stocks.symbol':'?1'}")
    List<Stock> findByStockSymbol(String userId,String symbol);
```

But it returns me all the stock that user has bought so I have to loop through each of them and I don't think it is best practice. Any help would  be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By having one document you make it more difficult to achieve consistency. Aim for separate documents linked by @DBRef similar to @ManyToOne in JPA.

Comment: Thank you that helps!